# Oracle SQL: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, ddl, create-table, ora-00907

I'm migrating a database from mySQL to Oracle SQL but I'm getting a "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error when creating a table. I've tried everything I can think of but still keep getting the same error.

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE menu
(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
restaurant_id varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
menu_name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
menu_description varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
menu_price varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
quantity int(11) DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

I think the problem is with the PRIMARY KEY as it's only table with PRIMARY KEYs that I get the error on. Apologies if this is an obvious question, I'm new to Oracle SQL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You tagged SQLDev. Are you using SQLDev's migration project to move your MySQL stuff over into Oracle? It will convert your tables for you.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle != MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE menu
(  id number(11,0)  GENERATED AS IDENTITY,    --IDENTITY <=> AUTO_INCREMENT
   restaurant_id varchar2(30) DEFAULT NULL,   --VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR
   menu_name varchar2(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   menu_description varchar2(500) DEFAULT NULL,
   menu_price varchar2(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   quantity number(11,0) DEFAULT '1',         --NUMBER(11,0) instead of INT(11)
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: You can also say INTEGER.